# Question around SOQL query on a Task and why I can't use whoid as a where clause

Tags: soql

This query works for me on the Task object. I am able to show WhoId as field

```
select id, subject, WhoId, Who.name, who. createddate  from task where owner.id ='0056F00000DWfjYQAT' and subject like 'outbound%'order by createddate desc
```

However wanted to narrow it down further by using the WhoId as a WHERE clause but that didn't work. I tried

```
select id, subject, WhoId, Who.name, who. createddate  from task where owner.id ='0056F00000DWfjYQAT' and subject like 'outbound%' and whoid like '00Q%'order by createddate desc
```

This is the error message I got

```
invalid operator on id field
```

Would like to understand why I can't do that? How can I rewrite my query to narrow down my search?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you are doing in your query, I am guessing you are *trying* to narrow down the query to only include `Task`s where the `Who` is a `Lead`.

Instead of trying to compare the `Id` prefix, you need to use a [polymorphic query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm). It's going to be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, WhoId,
        TYPEOF Who WHEN Lead THEN Name, CreatedDate END
    FROM Task
    WHERE OwnerId = '0056F00000DWfjYQAT'
        AND Subject LIKE 'outbound%'
        AND Who.Type = 'Lead'
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Note that, as per the [TYPEOF documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm), the fields after the `THEN` and before the `END` are fields from the `Who`, not from the `Task`.

This query may be a bit "belt and braces"; I'm not 100% sure you need the `AND Who.Type = 'Lead'` part of the WHERE clause, but logically you probably do.

Comment: Thanks Phil.

I will read this and try and wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

As per salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) for SOQL.

> The LIKE operator is supported for string fields only.

You have to query without whoid like filter and then filter using for loop.

```
   List<Task> tasksFilter1 = [select id, subject, WhoId, Who.name  from task where owner.id ='0056F00000DWfjYQAT' and subject like 'outbound%' order by createddate desc];
List<Task> tasksFilter2 = new List<Task>();
for(Task t : tasksFilter1 ) {
     if(t.whoid !=null && String.valueOf(t.whoid).startsWith('00Q')) {
         tasksFilter2.add(t);
     }
}
System.debug('Filtered result : '+tasksFilter2 );
```